# React Admin: How to run method before return <Edit> form view

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

Im making app in React-Admin Framework. Now I am creating the edit form:

`<Resource name="order" edit={OrderEdit} />`

And I want to decide whether to show [Edit View](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html) based on a record.

E.g If record 'id' from [data provider](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html) is equal to 5, display an alert and redirect to the main view '/orders':

```
const OrderEdit  = (props) => {
    const checkId = (id) => {
        if(id==5){
            alert('You cannot edit an order where ID Input is 5');
            useRedirect('/orders');
        }
    }

    //checkId(this.props.record.id); <=== HERE IS MY PROBLEM

    /*
        1. this.props.record.id = undefined;
        2. props.record.id = undefined;
        3. record.id = undefined;
    */

    return (
        <Edit {...props} >
            <SimpleForm>
                <TextInput
                    source="id"
                    label="ID Input"
                />
            </SimpleForm>
        </Edit>
    );
};
export default OrderEdit;
```

But I don't know how to access record.id before return.

I know that I can do it with [FunctionField](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#functionfield):

```
<FunctionField
    render={(record) =>{
        if(record) checkId(record.id)
        return null;
    }}
    label="test"
/>
```

But it doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `this.` since its a functional component where you pass props as an argument.

You could return null if record.id is not the correct, which is the same way as saying display nothing:

```
    if (checkId(this.props.record.id)) return null
    return (
        <Edit {...props} >
            <SimpleForm>
                <TextInput
                    source="id"
                    label="ID Input"
                />
            </SimpleForm>
        </Edit>
    );
```

Or more clean:

```
return checkId(this.props.record.id) ? null : (
    <Edit {...props} >
        <SimpleForm>
            <TextInput
                source="id"
                label="ID Input"
            />
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```

Comment: Ok, but there is no 'record' object in 'props'. 1. this.props.record.id = undefined;
2. props.record.id = undefined; 3. record.id = undefined;

Comment: You will have to pass record as a prop.

Comment: Record is undefined everywhere

Comment: What is record? Tell me more.

Comment: The <Edit> component calls dataProvider.getOne(), using the id from the URL. It also clones its child, and passes it the fetched record as record prop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can access the record in the Edit view component because it calls a `getOne` internally and forward the record to its child. So you can eventually wrap your form to access it like:

```
const WrapperForm = (props) => {
  const {record} = props;
  return (
    <SimpleForm {...props}>
      <TextInput source="id" label="ID Input"/>
    </SimpleForm>
  );
}
```